# Prove that $C^1[0,1]$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have to prove that $C^1[0,1]$ is complete with respect to the norm $\|f\|=|f(0)|+\int_0^1|f'(t)|dt$ is complete.

**My attempt:**

Let $f_n(t)$ be a Cauchy sequence from $C^1[0,1]$. We have:
$$\forall_{\epsilon>0} \exists_{N>0} \forall_{n,m>N} |f_n(0)-f_m(0)|+\int_0^1|f_n'(t)-f_m'(t)|dt < \epsilon$$

Now let $a \in [0,1]$. We have:
$$|f_n(a)-f_m(a)|\le|f_n(0)-f_m(0)|+|f_n(a)-f_m(a)-f_n(0)+f_m(0)\le|f_n(0)-f_m(0)|+|\int_0^af_n'(t)-f_m'(t)dt| \le|f_n(0)-f_m(0)|+\int_0^1|f_n'(t)-f_m'(t)|dt < \epsilon$$
So we have that for any fixed $x$ from $[0,1]$, $(f_n(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence, thus it is convergent to - let it be - f(x).

Now going with $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have:

$$\forall_{\epsilon>0} \exists_{N>0} \forall_{m>N} |f(0)-f_m(0)|+\int_0^1|f'(t)-f_m'(t)|dt < \epsilon$$

I don't know if that's ok...

Comment: Your attempt is doomed to fail, since $C^1([0,1])$ is **not** complete in that norm. If you consider only the subspace with $f(0) = 0$, you see that one's just $C^0([0,1])$ with the $L^1$-norm, which is one of the first examples of an incomplete space one encounters.

Comment: The "right" norm for $C^1[0,1]$ is $|f(0)|+ \max |f'|$, or $\max |f| + \max |f'|$. You really need a uniform bound on the derivatives, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: but my exercise book tells that it is complete with respect to exactly this norm I wrote...error?

Comment: @luka5z Yes, if your exercise book says $C^1$ is complete with that norm, it is wrong. Consider the sequence $g_n$, where $g_n$ is $0$ on $[0,1/2 - 2^{-n}]$, $1$ on $[1/2+2^{-n},1]$, and interpolates linearly to be continuous. Then let $f_n(t) = \int_0^t g_n(s)\,ds$. That gives you a Cauchy sequence (check that), and the only possible limit function is $0$ on $[0,1/2]$, $x-1/2$ on $[1/2,1]$, not continuously differentiable.

Comment: $C^1$ with the standard sup norm on [0,1] is also not complete, yes?