# How do I prove that $\Vert f \Vert=\vert f(0)\vert+\int_{0}^1 \vert f'(x)\vert\,dx$ defines a norm on $X=C^1[0, 1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't understand how should I go about checking the first condition ($\Vert f\Vert=0$ iff $f=0$) for a norm.

Comment: An indirect path : show that there exists an equivalence with other norms as established [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3375690); See as well the negative result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/763462). (results found using https://approach0.xyz/search/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\|f\|=0\iff|f(0)|+\int_0^1|f'(x)|\,\mathrm d x=0\iff |f(0)|=0\quad \text{and}\quad \int_0^1|f'|=0.$$

Since $f'$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $$\int_0^1|f'|=0\implies f'(x)=0,$$
for all $x\in [0,1]$. Therefore $f$ is constant on $[0,1]$. Since $f(0)=0$, we have that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Should probably be mentioned that $\int\vert f'\vert=0\Rightarrow f'=0$ requires continuity of $f'$. Which is a given here, but it might not be obvious.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos: Indeed, thanks for the remark.